# Является ли вопрос-дубликат по одной метке дубликатом для другой, более общей, метки?

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, дубликаты

Немного предыстории:

[Новый участник задал вопрос на английском языке - Why comparison of same coordinates gives answer false?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1085877/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-false), из-за чего получил пару минусов. В принципе это очевидный дубликат вопроса "почему одинаковые дробные числа выдают false при сравнении на равенство". Однако конкретно этот вопрос задан по конкретно метке.

Я ответил вполне конкретным решением с использованием конкретного функционала из конкретной библиотеки. Подумал, что негоже вполне адекватному вопросу быть в минусах, и попросил в чате добавить вопросу плюсов просто для нуля (о чем сразу же пожалел). В итоге вопрос закрыли дубликатом к [этому вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82).

---

**Непосредственно вопрос**: где заканчивается "это дубликат" и начинается "это принципиально новый и уникальный вопрос"?

Идти в оригинальный вопрос и писать там "а вот решение для Unity..." - это, имхо, бред.
Да и почему вопрос для конкретной метки/темы считается дубликатом к общему "каноничному" вопросу-ответу, если он имеет уникальное для метки/темы решение?

**P.S.**

Под "уникальным решением" я подразумеваю "каноничное" решение, которое принято использовать в рамках, в данном случае, движка Unity. Понятное дело, что внутри там всё равно используется `a - b < tolerance`.

Comment: Просить кого-либо вывести вопрос из минусов - это накрутка, за такое надо карать.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev а да? А проставление минусов нормальному вопросу - это что? Добросовестное использование данного инструментария? Что насчет эксплуатации золотой метки, кстати? Или на свой вопрос здесь я тоже плюсов накрутил не по делу? Ну а так, вперед, буду только рад получить пожизненный бан, если нынче именно по таким правилам работает русский стэк.

Comment: Минусы и плюсы - это использование права на выражение личного мнения. А золотая метка выдаётся за заслуги перед ресурсом и его пользователями, что гарантирует её применение во благо. Если вы с этим несогласны, то самый эффективный метод противодействия - заслужить свою и переоткрывать те вопросы, которые несправедливо закрыли, по-вашему мнению.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev за предложение спасибо, но я лучше воздержусь от траты времени на такое сообщество, чем буду в детский сад с переоткрытием вопросов играть :)

Comment: Ваше право. Те же, кто останутся дальше тратить время и силы на вклад в развитие ресурса, будут двигать его в том направлении, которое считают более благотворным для пользователей.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev да я уже понял, что ваше "благотворное для пользователей направление" - это душить вопросы и активность, лишь бы полномочия иной раз применить. Наличие власти не гарантирует ее применение во благо, а клин клином вышибать - это самое абсурдное, что я вообще слышал за 1.5 года на стэке. Удачи вам с вашим ресурсом и всего доброго.

Comment: Вы подвергаете сомнению правила и механизмы SO, а также заложенные в их основы демократические принципы? Что для вас "игры", то для сообщества способы саморегуляции.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мне кажется, закрывать не надо в том случае, когда есть уникальный ответ. Надо просто дать ссылку в комментариях, и соответствующий вопрос появится в списке связанных.

Answer (score 3):

Т.к. в данном случае вопрос «**Почему** сравнение одинаковых чисел выдает `false`?», то это ИМХО очевидный дубликат, подробный ответ на который есть в общем вопросе. Если бы вопрос явно звучал как-то так: «Какой хороший способ есть сравнивать числа с плавающей точкой в С#/Unity?», то это был бы отдельный вопрос.

Кроме того в том что вопрос признали дубликатом нет ничего страшного — AFAIK дубликаты не удаляются автоматически, а с хорошими ответами — и вручную... А то что вопросу накидали минусов — не совсем справедливо, но пусть остаётся на совести тех, кто их ставил...

Comment: На закрытый (дубликатом) вопрос нельзя дать ответ.

Answer (score -1):

Если для вопроса по одной метке находится вопрос схожий по смыслу из другой метки, то первоначальный следует закрыть как повтор, предварительно добавив к нему более общую метку из найденного вопроса.

Comment: Для якобы дубликата есть уникальное решение, которое слишком конкретное для общего вопроса.

Answer (score -1):

Я исхожу из того, что важнее всего донести концепцию.

`Mathf.Approximately` в контексте Unity правильный ответ, бесспорно. Но, как мне кажется, важнее всего понять суть. Название конкретного метода не даёт, в целом, ничего нового сверх того, что написано в вопросе с меткой [любой-язык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba) в данном случае. Да, вы написали, в чём проблема работы с числами с плавающей запятой. Но это и в вопросе старом было написано. Если человек поймёт суть, то он подобный метод и сам написать сможет.

Но в итоге, конечно, решают остальные участники, голосующие за закрытие.

Как вариант, можно создать один каноничный вопрос с ответом и там в ответе привести списком каноничные решения по различным языкам/технологиям.

Comment: Проблема в том, что вопрос закрыли не 5 голосами, а 3мя, один из которых с золотым знаком по метке. И то это случилось только потому что я в чате попросил плюсов вопросу поставить, иначе бы этот вопрос так и висел, но это уже другая тема. Да и это лишь пример, я хотел бы услышать мнение о ситуации в целом, а не в рамках данного вопроса.